# Deriving gradient of a single layer neural network w.r.t its inputs, what is the operator in the chain rule?

Tags: neural-networks, gradient

Problem is:

> Derive the gradient with respect to the input layer for a a single
>   hidden layer neural network using sigmoid for input -> hidden, softmax
>   for hidden -> output, with a cross entropy loss.

I can get through most of the derivation using the chain rule but I am uncertain on how to actually "chain" them together.

Define some notations

$ r = xW_1+b_1 $

$ h = \sigma\left( r \right) $, $\sigma$ is sigmoid function

$ \theta = hW_2+b_2 $,

$ \hat{y} = S \left( \theta \right) $, $S$ is softmax function

$ J\left(\hat{y}\right) = \sum_i y \log\hat{y}_i $ , $y$ is real label one-hot vector

Then by the chain rule,

$$
\frac{\partial J}{\partial \boldsymbol{x}} 
= \frac{\partial J}{\partial \boldsymbol{\theta}} \cdot \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{\theta}}{\partial \boldsymbol{h}} \cdot \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{h}}{\partial \boldsymbol{r}} \cdot \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{r}}{\partial \boldsymbol{x}} 
$$

Individual gradients are:

$$
\frac{\partial J}{\partial \boldsymbol{\theta}}  = \left( \hat{\boldsymbol{y}} - \boldsymbol{y} \right) 
$$
$$
\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{\theta}}{\partial \boldsymbol{h}} = \frac{\partial}{\partial \boldsymbol{h}} \left[ \boldsymbol{h}W_2 + \boldsymbol{b_2}\right] = W_2^T
$$
$$
\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{h}}{\partial \boldsymbol{r}} = h \cdot \left(1-h\right)
$$
$$
\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{r}}{\partial \boldsymbol{x}} = \frac{\partial}{\partial \boldsymbol{x}} \left[ \boldsymbol{x}W_1 + \boldsymbol{b_1}\right] = W_1^T
$$

Now we have to chain the definitions together. In single-variable this is easy, we just multiply everything together. In vectors, I'm not sure whether to use element-wise multiplication or matrix multiplication.

$$
\frac{\partial J}{\partial \boldsymbol{x}} 
= \left( \hat{\boldsymbol{y}} - \boldsymbol{y} \right) * W_2^T \cdot \left[\boldsymbol{h} \cdot \left(1-\boldsymbol{h}\right)\right] * W_1^T
$$

Where $\cdot$ is element-wise multiplication of vectors, and $*$ is a matrix multiply. This combination of operations is the only way I could seem to string these together to get a $1 \cdot D_x$ dimension vector, which I know $\frac{\partial J}{\partial \boldsymbol{x}} $ has to be.

My question is: what is the principled way for me to figure out which operator to use? I'm specifically confused by the need for the element-wise one between $W_2^T$ and $h$.

Thanks!

Comment: I realize finding the gradient w.r.t to the inputs is not often done. I believe this is a lead in to computing word embeddings, where you do have the option to optimize the "input" word vectors.

Comment: how didi you dervie dJ/dTheta

Answer (score 5):

I believe that the key to answering this question is to point out that the element-wise multiplication is actually **shorthand** and therefore when you derive the equations you *never* actually use it.

The actual operation is not an element-wise multiplication but instead a standard matrix multiplication of a gradient with a [Jacobian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant), **always**.

In the case of the nonlinearity, the Jacobian of the vector output of the non-linearity with respect to the vector input of the non-linearity happens to be a diagonal matrix.  It's therefore true that the gradient multiplied by this matrix is equivalent to the gradient of the output of the nonlinearity with respect to the loss element-wise multiplied by a vector containing all the partial derivatives of the nonlinearity with respect to the input of the nonlinearity, but this *follows* from the Jacobian being diagonal.  You must pass through the Jacobian step to get to the element-wise multiplication, which might explain your confusion.

In math, we have some nonlinearity $s$, a loss $L$, and an input to the nonlinearity $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$ (this could be any tensor).  The output of the nonlinearity has the same dimension $s(x) \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$---as @Logan says, the activation function are defined as element-wise.

We want $$\nabla_{x}L=\left({\dfrac{\partial s(x)}{\partial x}}\right)^T\nabla_{s(x)}L$$

Where $\dfrac{\partial s(x)}{\partial x}$ is the Jacobian of $s$.  Expanding this Jacobian, we get
\begin{bmatrix}
    \dfrac{\partial{s(x_{1})}}{\partial{x_1}} & \dots  & \dfrac{\partial{s(x_{1})}}{\partial{x_{n}}} \\
    \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    \dfrac{\partial{s(x_{n})}}{x_{1}} & \dots  & \dfrac{\partial{s(x_{n})}}{\partial{x_{n}}}
\end{bmatrix}

We see that it is everywhere zero except for the diagonal.  We can make a vector of all its diagonal elements $$Diag\left(\dfrac{\partial s(x)}{\partial x}\right)$$

And then use the element-wise operator.

$$\nabla_{x}L
=\left({\dfrac{\partial s(x)}{\partial x}}\right)^T\nabla_{s(x)}L
=Diag\left(\dfrac{\partial s(x)}{\partial x}\right) \circ \nabla_{s(x)}L$$

Answer (score 0):

Whenever backproportionate to an activation function, the operations become element-wise. Specifically, using your example, $\delta_2 =(\hat{y}-y)W_2^T$ is a backpropagation derivative and $a' = h \circ (1 -h)$ is an activation derivative, and their product are elementwise product, $\delta_2 \circ a'$. This because activation functions are defined as element-wise operations in neural network.

See the cs224d [lecture slides](http://cs224d.stanford.edu/lectures/CS224d-Lecture5.pdf) page 30, it might also help.