# Dimensions in single layer NN gradient

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, backpropagation, softmax, matrix-calculus

Given a neural network with one hidden sigmoid layer and softmax output layer, I want to derive the gradient of the cross entropy loss with respect to the first weight matrix. This is equivalent to the network described in [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/253460/derive-the-gradients-of-a-basic-neural-network), but in my derivation the dimensions mismatch.

\begin{align*}
    &J = CE(y,\hat{y})=-\sum_i y_i log(\hat{y}_i)\\
    &\hat{y} = softmax(z_2)\\
    &z_2 = hW_2+b_2\\
    &h = sigmoid(z_1)\\
    &z_1 = xW_1+b_1
\end{align*}
Where $W_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{D_x \times H}$, $b_1 \in \mathbb{R}^H$, $W_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{H \times D_y}$ and $b_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{D_y}$.

When deriving the gradients with respect to $W_1$, I use the chain rule similar to this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/194078/deriving-gradient-of-a-single-layer-neural-network-w-r-t-its-inputs-what-is-the), in which the gradient with respect to the input is calculated. The result should be:
$$
\frac{\partial J}{\partial \boldsymbol{W_1}} 
= \frac{\partial J}{\partial \boldsymbol{z_2}} \cdot \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{z_2}}{\partial \boldsymbol{h}} \cdot \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{h}}{\partial \boldsymbol{z_1}} \cdot \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{z_1}}{\partial \boldsymbol{W_1}} 
$$ 
The individual gradients for the first three derivations are:
$$
\frac{\partial J}{\partial \boldsymbol{z_2}}  = \left( \hat{\boldsymbol{y}} - \boldsymbol{y} \right) 
$$
$$
\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{z_2}}{\partial \boldsymbol{h}} = \frac{\partial}{\partial \boldsymbol{h}} \left[ \boldsymbol{h}W_2 + \boldsymbol{b_2}\right] = W_2^T
$$
$$
\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{h}}{\partial \boldsymbol{z_1}} = h \circ \left(1-h\right)
$$
Plugging them in into the original equation yields:
$$
\frac{\partial J}{\partial \boldsymbol{W_1}} 
= \left( \hat{\boldsymbol{y}} - \boldsymbol{y} \right) 
\cdot W_2^T 
\circ  h \circ (1 -h) 
\cdot \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{z_1}}{\partial \boldsymbol{W_1}} 
$$ 
Since in my understanding $ \hat{\boldsymbol{y}} - \boldsymbol{y} \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times D_y}$ and $W_2^T \in \mathbb{R}^{D_y \times H}$ and the multiplication with $h$ and $1-h$ is elementwise the result should be $\in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times H}$. No matter what the result of $\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{z_1}}{\partial \boldsymbol{W_1}}$ is, I can not see it to fit the dimensions, since the final result has to be in the dimensions of $W_1$. Where did I go wrong in my derivation.